# How to inject the Repository services in the bootstrap phase

Tags: spring, alfresco

I have a class named "NodeUtil" and that class have a three services injected in the bootstrap phase but once i trying to Log the service.toString() the value that printed is
proxy$.toString() .

I'm trying to initialize the services in the NodeUtil bean rather than initialize them using

```
Repository.getServiceRegistry(FacesContext ...).getSearchService()
```

I use the same thing in the file action-services-context.xml.

- I create a class.
- I set setter methods.
- I write a snipe of xml tag for NodeUtil Bean.

Can anyone tell me why this initiate an error and what the correct way.

Thanks

Comment: So what is the error? What were you expecting?

Comment: Artefacto, i think that i get it, where once the alfresco bootstrapping there is no Faces Context, so i will relay on the spring framework to inject the services proxies. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@Artefacto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/127724/artefacto) said, there's no issue here. When using Spring, you get a reference to a [Proxy](http://va/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class that wraps what you asked it to initialize. This has a number of (beneficial) effects, but definitely it's not an error.

You can see that `proxy$.toString()` as a proof that you really have a handle to an initialized instance of the class you need. I strongly suggest you to read more about how [Spring IoC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#overview-dependency-injection) works.

Comment: Yes, it is a spring declaration by using <bean ...> tag.